# How to create custom Navigation Bar Swift UI?

Tags: swiftui

I've been using default `navigation bar` (because it has the ability to enable swipes to close a View), but since my issue is to `hide` `NavBar` in a `RootView` and `show` when it disappears after Navigation to a `ChildView`, I faced a problem with my `ChildView` (it bounce up and down after manipulations with navbar). Hence I need a `custom NavBar` (perfectly would be with an ability to make swipes to hide it.)

Here you can see my code and [issue with NavBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62047764/how-to-fix-a-bug-of-half-closed-view-swiftui) that was solved and triggered the one you are reading.

## My RootView

```
struct ExploreView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
        VStack{
            HStack{
        
                NavigationLink(destination: MessagesView()){

                         Image("messages")
                        
                      }
 
                }
            }

        }
       
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
   
    }
}
```

## ChildView#

```
struct MessagesView: View {

    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var btnBack : some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                .font(.title)
        }
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
   
        ZStack{
            
        VStack{
            Spacer()

            HStack {
                btnBack
                    .padding(.leading, 10)


                Spacer()


                Button(action:{
                     self.show.toggle()
                 },label: {
                     Image("writemessage")
                     .foregroundColor(Color("blackAndWhite"))
                 }
                )
            }
        }
       
    
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .navigationBarHidden(true)   
    
     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom NavigationBar could look like this. Of course it can be individualized with colors and fontSizes etc. in whatever way you like:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: MessagesView()){
                        Text("Go to MessagesView")
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }
    }
}

struct MessagesView: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var btnBack : some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                .font(.title)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {

        ZStack{
            VStack{
                HStack {
                    btnBack
                        .padding(.leading, 10)
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()

                Text("MessagesView")
                Spacer()
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

To keep the Swipe-back gesture working even while the standard NavigationBar is disabled you need some addition under your SceneDelegate:

```
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. **First question** is : should I `hideNavbar` in `ChildView` and `RootView`? Second: where exactly should I put this extension to (in Scene Delegate)?It tells `Declaration is only valid at file scope`. **Third** : I used `@Binding` to connect with Navlink from RootView to ChildView, it doesnt navigate back. Any Ideas?

Comment: 1. I would hide NavBar everywhere if you use this concept. 2. The extension should be at the bottom of SceneDelegate. Under your last }. 3. self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() brings you back which is part of your backBtn. No binding needed in simple use-cases. If you need it for some other reasons .toggle()  it inside the action of your back button.

Comment: thanks for the answer! Nothing works, unfortunately.. Neither **swipe** nor **button**. (but bounce up issue disappeared )  **I added full code** of `Root And Child Views`

Comment: See my edited answer for both code blocks above. Tested on iPhone XS simulator.

Comment: Btw, are you familiar with paging transition? Like Snapchat and Instagram have in their menu (left photos right messages)?  Been trying with some libraries , but unsuccessfully.. [here is my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62052142/how-to-make-a-swipe-navigation-like-instagram-and-snapchat-have-swiftui)

Comment: No I am not, sorry. But I am sure on SO are other people who know a lot more then I do and can help!